# C++ linked lists deleting nodes

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I am trying to go through a singly linked list and delete all nodes that contain a certain char. I have been trying to fix a pointer error (it said glibc detected: double free or corruption) by looking up online and trying those suggestions but now I seem to be stuck in a loop after rewriting my original code. I think the I am at least stuck in the 3rd while loop, I have tried using and if/else statement but the same thing happens. I also get a segmentation fault sometimes.

Code:

```
int MonsterList::removeMonsterType(char monster){
  if(!isalpha(monster)) return 0;
  if(first == 0) return 0;

  int count = 0;
  char key = toupper(monster);

  MonsterNode *prev = first; //first is the ptr in the list this function is called on
  if(prev->next == 0){
    while(prev->id == key || prev->id == key+32){
      first = 0;
      delete prev; prev = 0;
      count++;
      return count;
    }
    return count;
  }

 MonsterNode *temp = prev->next;

 while(temp != NULL){
   while(prev->id == key || prev->id == key+32){
     first = temp;
     delete prev;
     prev = temp;
     temp = temp->next;
   }
   while(temp->id == key || temp->id == key+32){
     prev->next = temp->next;
     delete temp;
     temp = prev->next;
     count++;
   }
   prev = temp;
   temp = temp->next;
 }

 return count;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There is too much wrong with this code.  The solution should be much simpler than this.  You should try to completely start over and see what happens; keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

No wonder you're having such trouble.  You only need a single for loop.  Allow me to simplify your code [please pardon some gratuitous style edits].  Note this is untested and may not be perfect:

```
int
MonsterList::removeMonsterType(char monster)
{
    if (!isalpha(monster))
        return 0;

    // first is the ptr in the list this function is called on
    if (first == 0)
        return 0;

    int count = 0;
    char key = toupper(monster);

    MonsterNode *prev;
    MonsterNode *cur;
    MonsterNode *next;

    prev = NULL;
    for (cur = first;  cur != NULL;  cur = next) {
        // grab this _first_ so we have it before cur may be deleted (e.g. if
        // cur gets deleted cur->next is immediately invalid, but this will
        // remain)
        next = cur->next;

        if ((cur->id == key) || (cur->id == (key + 32))) {
            // link previous item to next item
            if (prev != NULL)
                prev->next = next;

            // replace first item in list
            else
                first = next;

            // delete the node and advance the count
            delete cur
            count++;

            continue;
        }

        // remember previous item
        prev = cur;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! Your code makes a lot of sense, when I test it though I am still getting the glidbc detected error. I think its because when i print out the list there is an '!' being printed out. This happened to me earlier too. I'm not sure if that means the last pointer is pointing at something wrong.

Comment: @puredreams7 I had to assume `first` was the list _head_ and a global  (e.g. was _not_ `this`), otherwise the code I gave won't work.  If glibc is saying "double free/corruption" [they usually occur together], this is slightly different than a segfault, although both can occur from the same type of bug.   If you can edit your question and post more code, I can help further.